# Can't replace \n to ,

Tags: python

Example: 
blahblahblah 
blahblahblah 
blahblahblah

Turn to: 
blahblahblah, blahblahblah, blahblahblah

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    temp = f.readlines()

for line in temp:
    line.replace('\n', ', ', end='')

print(temp)

input()
```

Comment: `temp = f.read().replace("\n", ", ")`

Comment: The string `.replace()` method *returns a new string*.  You are throwing the new string away, rather than storing it anywhere.  Also, it doesn't take an `end=` parameter, I have no idea what that's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `read()` is better for your case instead of `readlines()`.
You can do the following:

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    temp = f.read().replace("\n", ",")
print(temp)
```

Edit:
In case there is a new line in the end, the above code would give the output as:

> blahblahblah, blahblahblah, blahblahblah,

In order to remove the last comma, you can simply use `temp[:-1]`